# Unable to start a mariadb container on Azure, because mysql user doesn't seem to have access to the volume

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm just trying to start a simple mariadb container on azure with docker compose. Without linking to a volume it works, but whenever I try to use a volume to have some persistent storage, the container refuses to boot properly. Below my docker compose setup:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5.8
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=****
      - MYSQL_USER=****
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=****
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

volumes:
  data-volume:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: myshare
      storage_account_name: mystorage
```

I always get this error in the mariadb logs, so it looks like the mysql user doesn't have enough permissions for certain tasks. Although there are files written on the volume.

```
021-02-22 16:36:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.8+maria~focal started.
2021-02-22 16:36:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-02-22 16:36:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.8+maria~focal started.
2021-02-22 16:36:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files


PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:

'/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root password 'new-password'
'/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root -h  password 'new-password'

Alternatively you can run:
'/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation'

which will also give you the option of removing the test
databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
strongly recommended for production servers.

See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at https://mariadb.com/kb or the
MySQL manual for more instructions.

Please report any problems at https://mariadb.org/jira

The latest information about MariaDB is available at https://mariadb.org/.
You can find additional information about the MySQL part at:
https://dev.mysql.com
Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
https://mariadb.org/get-involved/

2021-02-22 16:36:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2021-02-22 16:36:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2021-02-22 16:36:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~focal) starting as process 162 ...
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for reading partial data failed.
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Tried to read 65536 bytes at offset 38400, but was only able to read 0.Cannot read from file. OS error number 13.
210222 16:36:49 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~focal
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 467860 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x49000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x32)[0x55611b833692]
Printing to addr2line failed
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x485)[0x55611b28ae45]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0)[0x7f01295d63c0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb)[0x7f01290dd18b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b)[0x7f01290bc859]
mysqld(+0x62dcbb)[0x55611af4fcbb]
mysqld(+0x610b88)[0x55611af32b88]
mysqld(+0xcd8946)[0x55611b5fa946]
mysqld(+0xcc3cbb)[0x55611b5e5cbb]
mysqld(+0xcc8b4b)[0x55611b5eab4b]
mysqld(+0xccce49)[0x55611b5eee49]
mysqld(+0xccd460)[0x55611b5ef460]
mysqld(+0x62636a)[0x55611af4836a]
mysqld(+0xc60c49)[0x55611b582c49]
mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x82)[0x55611b28deb2]
mysqld(+0x76b36a)[0x55611b08d36a]
mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x965)[0x55611b08e645]
mysqld(+0x68ab0b)[0x55611afacb0b]
mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x435)[0x55611afb26b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7f01290be0b3]
mysqld(_start+0x2e)[0x55611afa712e]
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Resource Limits:
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             4326                 4326                 processes 
Max open files            32184                32184                files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       4326                 4326                 signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us        
Core pattern: core

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 103:   162 Aborted                 "$@" --skip-networking --socket="${SOCKET}"
```

**2021-02-22 16:36:49 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.**

I already tried with a custom mariadb image, but without success

```
FROM mariadb:10.5.8

RUN chown 999:999 /var/lib/mysql
```

And when I start the container without the volume specification in my docker-compose file, and log into the container, I can see that the files were created by the mysql user ? What am I missing here ?

```
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql     32768 Mar  8 11:01 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        52 Mar  8 11:01 aria_log_control
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql       976 Mar  8 11:01 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 100663296 Mar  8 11:01 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  12582912 Mar  8 11:01 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  12582912 Mar  8 11:01 ibtmp1
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql      4096 Mar  8 11:01 mydatabase
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql         0 Mar  8 11:01 multi-master.info
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql      4096 Mar  8 11:01 mysql
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql      4096 Mar  8 11:01 performance_schema
```

Maybe also good to know, the volume was created via the docker aci feature. https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-compose-features/#persistent-volumes

**UPDATE**: I don't have this problem with the official mysql (5.7) docker image. It just works out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem for the Azure File Share. When you mount the File Share, then the mount point will have the `root` user as the owner and group. We can't change it, because it is designed by Azure. This issue is not fixed right now.

If you don't mind, I recommend you take a try with AKS and use the Azure disk as the volume. The issue will not happen in this way. See a similar issue [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#error-could-not-change-permissions-when-using-azure-files).

Comment: Thx for the answer Charles ! Now I don't have to look any further. I switched to the mysql image to circumvent this problem, but I will keep on using Azure cloud services :)

Comment: This was very helpful! In my AKS Azure File is the provider for the "default" storage class. I tried setting `securityContext.fsGroup`, `securityContext.fsGroupChangePolicy` and `chown`ing via initContainer and `chown`ing manually after startup. None worked for Azure File or Azure Blob Storage (`chown`ing actually did not change the user/group permissions although it exited with a zero error code. @Charles suggestion solved my issue.